# Can I name the field myself when I update in django view?

Tags: django

Can I name the field myself when I update in django view?

ex

if field value is "ca2"

Can I use this as the field value for the update function of django-orm?

when i try this code below error is occured

```
AttributeError: 'CategoryNick' object has no attribute 'update'
```

```
def update_shortcut_nick(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        ca_id = request.POST['ca_id']
        field = request.POST['field']
        ca_nick_update = request.POST['ca_nick_update']

        print('update id : ',ca_id)
        print('update field  : ',field)
        print('update value : ',ca_nick_update)

        update = CategoryNick.objects.get(id=ca_id).update( field = ca_nick_update)
        # .update(field = ca_nick_update)

        print('update success : ' , update.id);

        return JsonResponse({
            'message': 'shortcut category nick name update success ' +ca_nick_update,
        })
    else:
        return redirect('/wm/shortcut')
```

and i changed to get => filter 
but

```
        update = CategoryNick.objects.filter(id=ca_id).update(field = ca_nick_update)
```

error is still occured :

```
CategoryNick has no field named 'field'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform **update** on .get, because .get first gives you the object not queryset. do notice .filter, .update and all other methods are chainable which means you can write a query as shown below.

```
Student.objects.filter(year="3").exclude(house="slytherin").update(points=250)
```

As you can assume, you can keep adding more methods to the chain to chop and change the query to achieve what you want. and this is possible because for each of these operations Django returns a **queryset**. which means when **.filter** is called, a new **queryset** will be returned and the same with **.exclude** and **.update**. and that's how chaining is possible.

As per your case, because you used **.get** and you broke the chain, now you got the actual object, not the **queryset**. However, you can perform the same operation using **.filter** and update on it as shown below

```
Student.objects.filter(id=22).update(house="Hufflepuff)
```

Comment: i change for filter but error is occured => django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CategoryNick has no field named 'field'

Comment: Are you sure CategoryNick has 'field' defined in the model?

Comment: real category name is ca2 but i want to update ca2 field by filter(filedname=field).update(ca_nick_update) is this possiable?

Comment: if you can show me the model for CategoryNick it would be helpful